# All of the option to replace an unknown number of characters

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to find an algorithm that for an unknown number of characters in a string, produces all of the options for replacing some characters with stars.

For example, for the string "abc", the output should be:

```
*bc   
a*c  
ab*  
**c  
*b*  
a**
***
```

It is simple enough with a known number of stars, just run through all of the options with for loops, but I'm having difficulties with an all of the options.

Comment: HINT: *Permutations, not combinations.*  Your inner for loops (in some, if not all cases), should start at the ending value of your outer for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every star combination corresponds to binary number, so you can use simple cycle

```
for i = 1 to 2^n-1
```

where n is string length
and set stars to the positions of 1-bits of binary representations of i
for example: i=5=101b =>  * b *

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a binary increment problem.
You can create a vector of integer variables to represent a binary array isStar and for each iteration you "add one" to the vector.

```
bool AddOne (int* isStar, int size) {
    isStar[size - 1] += 1
    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        if (isStar[i] > 1) {
            if (i = 0) { return true; }
            isStar[i] = 0;
            isStar[i - 1] += 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That way you still have the original string while replacing the characters

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple binary counting problem, where `*` corresponds to a `1` and the original letter to a `0`. So you could do it with a counter, applying a bit mask to the string, but it's just as easy to do the "counting" in place.

Here's a simple implementation in C++:

(**Edit:** The original question seems to imply that at least one character must be replaced with a star, so the count should start at 1 instead of 0. Or, in the following, the post-test `do` should be replaced with a pre-test `for`.)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// A cleverer implementation would implement C++'s iterator protocol.
// But that would cloud the simple logic of the algorithm.

class StarReplacer {
  public:
    StarReplacer(const std::string& s): original_(s), current_(s) {}

    const std::string& current() const { return current_; }

    // returns true unless we're at the last possibility (all stars),
    // in which case it returns false but still resets current to the
    // original configuration.
    bool advance() {
      for (int i = current_.size()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (current_[i] == '*') current_[i] = original_[i];
        else {
          current_[i] = '*';
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  private:
    std::string original_;
    std::string current_;
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  for (int a = 1; a < argc; ++a) {
    StarReplacer r(argv[a]);
    do {
      std::cout << r.current() << std::endl;
    } while (r.advance());
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```